# Why ReadOnlySpan may not be used as a type argument for generic delegates and generic methods?

Tags: c#, dry

I understand why `ReadOnlySpan` may not be used as a type argument for generic classes. `ReadOnlySpan` is stack only and therefore it cannot be used as field types, field members live in the heap like its container object. However return values and arguments are always stack only, so why `ReadOnlySpan` cannot be used as type argument for generic delegates and generic methods?

Here you have an example illustrating what I'm saying:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate TResult MyFunc<TResult>(ReadOnlySpan<char> arg);

        static int GetSpanLength(ReadOnlySpan<char> span)
        {
            return span.Length;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var span = "hello".AsSpan();

            MyFunc<int> func1 = GetSpanLength;
            var result1 = DoSomething(func1, span);

            // The type 'ReadOnlySpan<char>' may not be used as a type argument
            Func<ReadOnlySpan<char>, int> func2 = GetSpanLength;

            //The type 'ReadOnlySpan<char>' may not be used as a type argument
            var result = DoSomething<int, ReadOnlySpan<char>>(func2, span);


        }

        static TResult DoSomething<TResult, T>(Func<T, TResult> func, T arg)
        {
            return func(arg);
        }

        static TResult DoSomething<TResult>(MyFunc<TResult> func, ReadOnlySpan<char> arg)
        {
            return func(arg);
        }

    }
}
```

It's very unfortunate because it forces me to have two identical versions of DoSomething method, making my code very WET.

NOTE: for projects targeting .NET Framework you need to install System.Memory Nuget Package.

Comment: What if the method does something with its `T` that is not allowed for `ReadOnlySpan`? C# generics are not like C++ templates, and the same code must apply to all possible instances (even if different code can be generated for value and reference types). `ReadOnlySpan<T>` is allowed, but substituting in a `Span` for any generic `T` can't be.

Comment: byte != char, you can't implicitly convert types like this. Try instead: `var result = DoSomething<int, ReadOnlySpan<char>>(func2, span);`

Comment: @JeroenMostert. It make sense, for example DoSomething might do: `object obj = arg;` which is allowed for everything but span, boxing is not allowed

Comment: @Igor, it's a typo, I'll fix it.

Comment: Have you tried lifting it with ReadOnlyMemory. The thing is, when you are working with Span, you are working with low level code, for performance reasons. Typical DRY SOLID programming doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @Igor, .net core or .net framework. The example code targets .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: @Aron, ReadOnlyMemory will work, but I need ReadOnlySpan because I'm working with unmanaged memory

Comment: `ReadOnlySpan` <= That is not available in the .net framework (any version). It is a .NET Core type. So your above example won't work with .net framework, hence the edit and added comment for anyone trying to use your [mcve].

Comment: @Aron, yes I'm currently repeating lots of code, which seems very awful.

Comment: @Igor, look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/ , on the dependencies section it mentions .NET Framework 4.5. And my console app is targeting .net fx 4.7.2 indeed.

Comment: That would be useful to include in the comment above your code (same place I mentioned .NET Core). For anyone that has not used that NuGet package before it is not intuitive that this needs to be included. If you search on the missing type the first couple of results lead you to the .NET Core documentation.

Comment: @Igor added note

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [post](https://adamsitnik.com/Span/#span-must-not-be-a-generic-type-argument) from Adam Sitnik says

> Let’s consider following C# code:
>
> ```
> Span<byte> Allocate() => new Span<byte>(new byte[256]);
>
> void CallAndPrint<T>(Func<T> valueProvider) // no generic requirements for T
> {
>     object value = valueProvider.Invoke(); // boxing!
>
>     Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
> }
>
> void Demo()
> {
>     Func<Span<byte>> spanProvider = Allocate;
>     CallAndPrint<Span<byte>>(spanProvider);
> }
> ```
>
> As you can see the non-boxing requirement can not be ensured today if
> we allow the Span to be generic type argument. One of the possible
> solutions could be to introduce new generic constraint: stackonly. But
> then all the managed compilers would have to respect it and ensure the
> lack of boxing and other restrictions. This is why it was decided to
> simply forbid using Span as a generic argument.

Comment: So we can't even use it in Tuples... C# is starting to have more gotchas than C++ and for all the wrong reasons ;(