# How can I use reflection to instance a class which takes ReadOnlySpan as a constructor argument?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have code like this:

```
    // lookup the object type, instance passing the data as constructor
    //all registered types must implement ctor passed ReadOnlySpan<byte>
    public static object InterpretPayload(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)
    {
        var key = bytes[0];
        if (!TypeLookup.ContainsKey(key))
            return null;
        Type type = TypeLookup[key];
        var created = Activator.CreateInstance(type, bytes);
        return created;
    }
```

`TypeLookup` maps numeric values to class types, in a weird sort of factory method pattern. However when changing my codebase to use `ReadOnlySpan` over `byte[]` I now get a compiler error that `bytes` isn't an object, which it isn't.

Is there another way to do this? I believe `Activator` tries to find the best ctor based on what I pass in, seems I need to do this more explicitly. Can I use reflection another way or have I found a case reflection *can't* emulate calling the ctor directly?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use reflection to obtain a (relatively) strongly-typed delegate, so that the `ReadOnlySpan` instance can be passed without boxing (which is not allowed for this type due to magic special-cased lifetime management)

Starting from the example for [Expression.Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.parameter?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Parameter_System_Type_):

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

delegate object CtorPattern<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> s);


// Creating a parameter for the expression tree.
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ReadOnlySpan<byte>));

// get your type
// get your ConstructorInfo by calling type.GetConstructor(...)

// Creating an expression for the constructor call and specifying its parameter.
var ctorCall = Expression.New(type, ctorinfo, param);


// The following statement first creates an expression tree,
// then compiles it, and then runs it.
var delegateCtor = Expression.Lambda<CtorPattern<byte>>(
ctorCall, new ParameterExpression[] { param }).Compile();

// call it
var created = delegateCtor(bytes);
```

You may want to cache the `delegateCtor` object in your type lookup instead of creating it anew every time.

Comment: You can't specify `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` as a generic type argument like that, this won't compile.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: The restriction is that lambdas cannot "capture" an instance of ReadOnlySpan<T>, not that they can't have it as a parameter.  But perhaps one can't use `Func<ReadOnlySpan<T>, object>` and need a specialized delegate definition?

Comment: No, you're not allowed to use ref structs as generic type arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155438/why-readonlyspan-may-not-be-used-as-a-type-argument-for-generic-delegates-and-ge